# OpenCV Python and SIFT features

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I know there is a lot of questions about **Python** and **OpenCV** but I didn't find help on this special topic.

I want to extract **SIFT keypoints** from an image in python OpenCV.

I have recently installed OpenCV 2.3 and can access to SURF and MSER but not SIFT.
I can't see anything related to SIFT in python modules (cv and cv2) (well I'm lying a bit: there are 2 constants: `cv2.SIFT_COMMON_PARAMS_AVERAGE_ANGLE` and `cv2.SIFT_COMMON_PARAMS_FIRST_ANGLE`).

This puzzles me since a while.
Is that related to the fact that some parts of OpenCV are in C and other in C++?
Any idea?

P.S.: I have also tried pyopencv (another python binding for OpenCV <= 2.1) without success.

Comment: Did you built OpenCV from sources?

Comment: Yes I have build OpenCV 2.3 from source using options CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE, CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON,WITH_QT=ON (the compilation works without problems).

Comment: The guys at willowgarage put the documentation for OpenCV 2.3 online [link](http://opencv.itseez.com/). Apparently features2d in python don't include much of the stuff.

Answer (score 6):

I can't say whether this is the reason SIFT was not available via Python for OpenCV 2.3 (as the original question asks). However, [the patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6711293) which was preventing SIFT from being included in OpenCV expired on 2020-03-06.

The distributed build of OpenCV now includes SIFT since version 4.4.0, accessible via `cv2.SIFT_create()` in Python.

See [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d7/d60/classcv_1_1SIFT.html) for further information on its use.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute SIFT features using OpenCV python bindings as follows:

```
  import cv2

  sift = cv2.SIFT()
  keypoints, descriptors = sift.detectAndCompute(imgray,None)
```

Comment: SIFT() is not working with cv2 library.
i tried Python(x,y) as well, but with no success.

Can u tell, from where u got the library? did u compile from source or any other method?

Answer (score 0):

SIFT has been [patented](http://www.google.com/patents/US6711293?hl=nl) and is not free for commercial use.

But if you want to use it for educational purposes, it's simple:

```
pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python
```

and then you can do

```
import cv2

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu you can fix with installing this version of opencv-contrib

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.0.12
```

Comment: This says the same thing as an answer from last year. If the version is important, clarify the other answer. It's also missing a lot of information to be a decent answer.